# Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException I

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

image source not readable in laravel 8 in intervention i've tried checking if path exist and it does and tried reinstalling intervention but it doesnt work still new to laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;

class PostsController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }
  public function create()
  {
    return view('posts.create');
  }
  public function store()
  {
    $data  = request()->validate([
        // 'another' => '',
        'caption' => 'required',
        'image' => ['required', 'image'],
    ]);

    // open an image file
    $image = Image::make(public_path('storage/{$imagePath}'))->fit(1200, 1200);
    $image->save();
    $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

    auth()->user()->posts()->create([
      'caption' => $data['caption'],
      'image' => $imagePath,
    ]);

    return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
  }
}
```

i dont know if its the public_path or what making the error help here!!

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you are trying to load a file literally named `{$imagePath}` ... you would have to store the uploaded file to disk before trying to load it from the disk

Comment: i already added images now im trying to display on fit them same sizes

Comment: You've defined `$imagePath` after trying to use it. Also, I recommend reading the [Laravel storage docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#retrieving-files) first.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked.

```
public function store()
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'caption' => 'required',
        'image' => ['required', 'image'],
    ]);

    
    $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads','public');
    //dd($imagePath);

    $img = ImageManagerStatic::make(storage_path().'/app/public/'.$imagePath);
    $img ->fit(400,400);
    $img -> save(storage_path().'/app/public/'.$imagePath);

    
    return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
}
```